# Fluent Validation with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, fluentvalidation

We've MVC-2 application with Fluent Validation (Visual Studio 2010). Recently we migrated it to Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5. After upgrading the Fluent Validation with NuGet, I get the compilation error for following members.

Can't find  `namespace FluentValidation.Mvc.MetadataExtensions`

I'm using `UIHint, DataType, DisplayName` members from `FluentValidation.Mvc.MetadataExtensions.MetadataExtensions` class. Which class should I use to fix errors?

**EDIT**

Broken code

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(class1Validator))]
public partial class class1: BusinessBase<decimal>
{
}

public class class1Validator: FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<class1>
{
    public class1Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.FirstName).NotEmpty().Length(1, 60).UIHint("First Name"); //giving error for UIHint
        RuleFor(o => o.Dob).DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Date).GreaterThan(DateTime.MinValue).LessThan(DateTime.Now); //giving error for datatype

    }
}

 public class SearchValidator : FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<SearchCriteria>
{
    public SearchValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Id).DisplayName("User ID"); //giving error for DisplayName in both lines
        RuleFor(o => o.LastName).DisplayName("Last Name");           

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post the broken code?

Comment: Those are attributes I believe from the .NET libraries. To be sure that FLuentAssertions didn't create their own attributes with the same name, I checked and didn't find a reference. 

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/609819a310c0493abd9b65a309c036bcd21ddbea/src/FluentValidation.Mvc3/FluentValidationModelMetadataProvider.cs

Comment: @DerekVanCuyk In old app running on MVC 2, it is in the `FluentValidation.Mvc.dll, v2.0.50727` assembly. I checked in VS 2010. In VS 2013 I added reference to  `FluentValidation.Mvc.dll`, but didnt help

Comment: I see them. They're extension methods and they are defined in the file. What version of FLuentValidation.Mvc are you using?

Comment: The version  is 1.3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that these extension methods are deprecated. I created a web project to do some research.

In any recent versions (FluentValidation.Mvc3+), I cannot find the extension methods.

When I created a project with FluentValildation.Mvc2, they exist.

You will need to either use the older library (and I don't know how well they play with the newer versions of MVC) or use the corresponding data annotations for each of the deprecated extension methods.

```
public class BusinessBase<T>
{
   [UIHint("First Name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean to say the in `System.data.dataannotation` namespace?

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel